# Order 2D array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I try found any solution but I could not find it.

In Swift 4, I have the next array:

```
[ ["839", "Huergo"], ["733", "Lavaisse"], ["732", "Pedro De Vega"]  ["824", "Obispo Boneo"],["727", "Hernandarias"], ["741", "Padre Genesio"], ["852", "Obispo Principe"]]
```

I need to order alphabetically by the second column, and get as a final array:

```
[["727", "Hernandarias"], ["839", "Huergo"], ["733", "Lavaisse"], ["824", "Obispo Boneo"], ["852", "Obispo Principe"], ["741", "Padre Genesio"], ["732", "Pedro De Vega"]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it this way:

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0[1] < $1[1] }
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) of `sorted(by:)` method, it says:

> Returns the elements of the collection, sorted using the given
> predicate as the comparison between elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    return first[1] < second[1]
}
```